# How to remove duplicates based on a condition regarding date values using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicate customer Ids based on the condition that only if the dates associated with the customer are within 10 days of one another then it should be dropped. The only row which should remain would be the latest date.

I know to remove duplicates based on a specific column one would use the following code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Date', keep='last')
```

However I am not sure how to apply further conditions to it.

This is the code used to create the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(10012,'2019-01-14'),(10015,'2019-01-16'), 
(10018,'2019-02-25'), (10020,'2019-02-17'),(10012,'2019-01-18'), 
(10015,'2019-02-26')],columns =['Customer ID', 'Date']

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Customer ID `10012` appears twice and the dates are within 10 days of one another so I expect the row with the earliest date to be removed.

Customer ID `10015` also appears twice, however the dates are more than 10 days apart so it should not be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can try with [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`series.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df[~df.groupby('Customer ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days.le(10)]
```

---

```
   Customer ID       Date
0        10012 2019-01-14
1        10015 2019-01-16
2        10018 2019-02-25
3        10020 2019-02-17
5        10015 2019-02-26
```

EDIT:

```
m=(df['Customer ID'].isin(df.loc[df.groupby('Customer ID')['Date'].diff()
                                           .dt.days.le(10),'Customer ID']))
pd.concat([df[~m],df[m].groupby('Customer ID')['Date'].max().reset_index()]).sort_index()
```

---

```
   Customer ID       Date
0        10012 2019-01-18
1        10015 2019-01-16
2        10018 2019-02-25
3        10020 2019-02-17
5        10015 2019-02-26
```

Comment: This does manage to remove duplicates if the dates are 10 days apart but I want to keep the latest date instead.